# Trying to make a graph using matplotlib in Python, novice programmer in need of assistance

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

What's causing these errors?

-----------Code-----------

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('bmh')

ages_x = [15, 19, 24, 29, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59, 64]

py_dev_y = [60, 560, 2110, 2760, 1930, 1190, 620, 340, 200, 120, 100]

plt.plot(ages_x, py_dev_y, '#5a7d9a', marker='o', linewidth=3, label='Python')


plt.title("Fuck it, here it is")

plt.legend(['All Devs', 'Python'])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.ylabel('Amount of devs who took the survey')
plt.xlabel('Ages')

plt.show()
```

----------Error------------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/usr/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    plt.plot(ages_x, py_dev_y, '#5a7d9a', marker='o', linewidth=3, label='Python')
  File "C:\Users\usr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2840, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "C:\Users\usr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1743, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\usr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 273, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 399, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (12,) and (1,)
```

-----------What I want it to do---------

I'm trying to get it to display a graph that shows ages and the amount of people that took the survey in a line graph

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: That's not the error message I see. I see ...`but have shapes (12,) and (11,)`. Note the 11, not 1.

Comment: Indeed, your `ages_x` and `py_dev_y` have different lengths. This looks like you made a data entry error.

Comment: `plt.plot(ages_x[1:], py_dev_y, '#5a7d9a', marker='o', linewidth=3, label='Python')` - will work with that data.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Cheers, I had two 29s in ages_x.

Comment: @wwii Thanks for the reply, I'll have to keep that in mind for when I make graphs in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a different number of `ages_x` (12 values in the list) vs. `py_dev_y` (11 values in the list). I just added an extra element in `py_dev_y` (90 as the last list value) and plot works.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('bmh')

ages_x = [15, 19, 24, 29, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, 54, 59, 64]

py_dev_y = [60, 560, 2110, 2760, 1930, 1190, 620, 340, 200, 120, 100, 90]

plt.plot(ages_x, py_dev_y, '#5a7d9a', marker='o', linewidth=3, label='Python')


plt.title("Fuck it, here it is")

plt.legend(['All Devs', 'Python'])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.ylabel('Amount of devs who took the survey')
plt.xlabel('Ages')

plt.show()
```

Resulting plot:
[image]